# publish to multiple brokers

Tags: go, paho

I want to implement some sort of message fanout using https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang.

I was expecting the client to connect and publish to all the brokers. But I can see in their respective dashboards that it just connects to 1 of those brokers.

```golang
tgOpts := mqtt.NewClientOptions()
for _, target := range targets {
    tgOpts.AddBroker(target)
}
```

Do I have to create one client per target broker, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MQTT is a topic-based model, 1 broker has multiple clients, not the other way around.

Some brokers (e.g. mosquitto) support [bridging](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-bridge-configuration/), which allows to build a fanout setup across brokers, but this setup is at broker level, the core MQTT functionality is still 1 broker per client connection. If you want to publish to multiple brokers, you'd need to connect to each one and publish individually.

Comment: Do you happen to know what's the purpose of this function, then? Why can I add multiple brokers to it? Those are appended to a slice each time the method is called.  `o.Servers = append(o.Servers, brokerURI)` https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/d978c5690736cf7bac9f1ac6a47897885211ee4f/options.go#L164

Comment: If you continue reading the code a bit you'll find [this place](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/d978c5690736cf7bac9f1ac6a47897885211ee4f/client.go#L384) where `o.Servers` is used. That should give you an answer that it stops after the first successful connection ([here](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang/blob/d978c5690736cf7bac9f1ac6a47897885211ee4f/client.go#L408)).